# How to add mail subjetct in custom mail on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, email, transactional-mail

I try to add `mail subject` in my custom mail, but i can't find anything  about this.

My code for sending emails looks like this:

```
$from = array('email' => "info@info.nl", 'name' => 'info');
$this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
$transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('medipoint_template_lend')
    ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
    ->setFrom($from)
     ->addTo($to)
    ->getTransport();
$transport->sendMessage();
$this->inlineTranslation->resume();
```

Does anyone know how to add subject to maill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you have to use an email template. The subject is then defined inside that template using something as such

```
<!--@subject Subject Of your email  @-->
```

In our module we used a helper to get the custom template and send the email.

Comment: so i just need to add  <!--@subject [subject] @--> at the begining of email template?

Comment: i did this but nothing happen